# Matching end of line position using m flag with different line ending styles

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to wrap each line that starts with "## " with tags. Trying to achieve a GitHub/Stackoverflow-like syntax for text formatting.

This is what I got:

```
$value = preg_replace('/^## (.*)$/m', '<p>$1</p>', $value);
```

After googling for quite a while this seems the right solution, however it doesn't work as expected or I just don't understand something.

Example text:

```
## Some header 1

Some text that doesn't need to be altered

## Some header 2
```

And this is the result:

```
<p>Some header 1
</p>

Some text that doesn't need to be altered

<p>Some header 2</p>
```

As you can see, the second header gets processed fine as it's at the end of the text. The first header, however, gets an extra new line at the end before the closing tag. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: The syntax used by github is MarkDown. I suggest you to use existing library like https://github.com/erusev/parsedown to parse your text

Comment: didn't found any issue in your code, have a look at https://3v4l.org/I8ICB

Comment: That is interesting. Try `'/(*ANYCRLF)^## (.*)$/m'`

Comment: It did work, Wiktor, thank you! You should make it an answer. What I found out it was actually adding a "\r" at the end of that string, not a "\n". I'm working in Laravel if it makes any difference. What does this (*ANYCRLF) part mean?

Comment: I can see that online code working perfectly, Chetan, that's weird.

Comment: Thanks, Fabien, but I just need a couple of header tags with specific markdown. Good to know what github uses though!

Comment: *"an extra new line at the end before the closing tag. How do I get rid of that?"* -- why would you do that? You are generating HTML, the newlines do not matter in this context.

Comment: For the record, [so] also uses [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for questions and answers and a reduced version of it for comments.

Comment: @Alexander I was away for a long time. I posted an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your current PCRE settings, a  dot matches all chars other than LF (`\n`, line feed), and thus, it matches CR (`\r`, carriage return), and that is also a line break char.

PCRE supports overriding of the default newline (and therefore the behavior of the `$` anchor). To make the `.` match all characters  but CR and LF, turn on the corresponding flag:

```
'/(*ANYCRLF)^## (.*)$/m'
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

`$` will assert the end of line before `\r\n`.

See more about this and other verbs at [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#pcre):

> By default, when PCRE is compiled, you tell it what to consider to be a line break when encountering a `.` (as the dot it doesn't match line breaks unless in [dotall mode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall)), as well the `^` and `$` anchors' behavior in [multiline mode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#). You can override this default with the following modifiers:
>
> ✽ `(*CR)` Only a carriage return is considered to be a line break
> ✽ `(*LF)` Only a line feed is considered to be a line break (as on Unix)
> ✽ `(*CRLF)` Only a carriage return followed by a line feed is considered to be a line break (as on Windows)
> ✽ `(*ANYCRLF)` Any of the above three is considered to be a line break
> ✽ `(*ANY)` Any Unicode newline sequence is considered to be a line break
>
> For instance, `(*CR)\w+.\w+` matches `Line1\nLine2` because the dot is able to match the `\n`, which is not considered to be a line break. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jN2fU8/1).